# JBoss same context root path for two wars

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, servlet-filters, application-server

I have a problem with servlet mapping and context root paths in my application. Right now I have a big war which I am going to split a little bit and allow to deploy as a few standalone smaller application.

Previously I had a context root path set to e.g.:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>/sampleApp</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

All worked fine. However, now I created another war which is an extracted part from the previous one. When I use a different context root it works as expected.

The problem is I cannot change the URL the application is accessed by. It means for the extracted application I also have to use the same context path.

How can it be achieved? I am using JBoss EAP 7.1

Comment: Two deployments can't have the same context. This is more than likely true on all application servers.

Comment: this would break the EE spec.  1 deployment maps to a unique context.  your best best would be to figure out a way to federate the deployments.  ultimately, if you need the "original" URI's to work, you can redirect them to your new context binding.

Comment: How do you expect, the server to know which of both applications to serve?

Comment: Under-rated question. There should be a way to decouple and remap any arbitrary URL pattern to a chosen app.